# Eager load polymorphic relationship straight after creating it

Tags: model, laravel-5, eloquent, polymorphic-associations

I have a `Project` model, which `hasMany` `Node` models. `Node` model is morphable:

```
public function nodeable()
{
   return $this->morphTo();
}
```

And it can be morphed into `Text` model or `Video` model.

Example:

```
public function node()
{
   return $this->morphOne(Node::class, 'nodeable');
}
```

It all works perfectly, the one issue I have at the moment is that I need to retrieve a `nodeable` model straight after creating the `Node`. For example:

```
$project = factory(\App\Project::class)->create();
$video = factory(\App\Video::class)->create();
$node = new App\Node;
$project->nodes()->save($node);
$video->node()->save($node);
```

Now I need to `return` the newly created `Node` along with its `nodeable` relationship model.

One way to do this would be:

`return App\Node::with('nodeable')->find($node->id)`

which works fine, but as you can see, I'm querying the database, when technically everything I need should already be accessible when creating the model, right?

Is it not possible to just return that `nodeable` model without having to execute a separate query for it?